# Do the stone soldiers move in a predicable pattern?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-ages

The owl statue told me that the stone statues in the Moonlit Grotto don't fear swords. I have figured out that I have to hit them with bombs, but I keep running out because they don't seem to go where I drop the bombs. I tried watching them to see if there was a pattern but it seems that they just go wherever at random. This makes it really hard to hit them.

Is there any sort of pattern to their movement or strategy I can use to hit them all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure their pattern is random. I haven't played Ages, but I've played Seasons; I'm pretty sure you can stun them with the boomerang (if you have it). I'd recommend trying to stun them then throw a bomb to ensure a hit. In most games they are also vulnerable to arrows, if you have the bow you could try that too.

Comment: I don't have a bow or a boomerang yet so I can't use those. I just have a shovel and bombs and the seeds.

Comment: Which seeds do you have? Pegasus seeds stun enemies, those might work. I'm not sure if scent seeds would effect them, you might be able to clump them together with scent seeds.

Comment: I have scent ones and mystery ones and the ones that set stuff on fire.

Comment: Hmm... I've been looking up walk-throughs for that area and each one just says to use bombs to kill them. It says there are bushes near by to get more bombs if you're running low. Otherwise it sounds like it's trial and error.

Comment: In think what you need to do is wait to throw the bombs until they're close to exploding, and then you just toss it directly at them or in their path.

Comment: As soon as you get the bow, be sure to use it in same time than the bombs to throw the bomb with the arrow

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do, if you're running out of bombs but fine on health, is to hold a bomb over your head and follow a soldier around until it explodes. It's a much more reliable way of catching them in the explosion, but it will mean you take more damage, both from the explosion and from getting hit while following them around. Obviously, if you've been using the Bomb Ring you will need to unequip it for this to work.